# Expo and Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, expo, create-react-native-app

I am trying to build a react-native-app on a vagrant linux box.

I am trying to access the app on my phone using expo but it just does not work.

Has anyone managed to make this work with port forwarding or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this a little more specific, the vagrant file should include the following line(the ip address is optional):
    `config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "ip address"`

for example:

1. `config.vm.network "public_network"`
2. `config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.9"`

Here are a couple of useful links:

1. [Youtube tutorial by sureshkm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRnVD_5X5SI&index=6&list=PLb681ctiE-83RT39Cw7IIBCT9w3rjX0-f)
2. [Vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the linux box on the same network as the phone.

Comment: To make this a little more specific, the vagrant file should include the following line: