# Expo + vagrant, metro bundle doesn't work

Tags: react-native, vagrant, expo

I created a VM to work on expo. I can't run Metro Bundle in browser in my host on 19002 port. Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME = Socket.ip_address_list.find { |ai| ai.ipv4? && !ai.ipv4_loopback? }.ip_address

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/ubuntu1804"
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
        v.name = "mobile-app"
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus = 1
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ioapic", "on"]
    end

    config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/home/vagrant/workspace", type: 'nfs', mount_options: ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']

    config.vm.hostname = "mobile-app"
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.40"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 19000, host: 19000
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 19001, host: 19001
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 19002, host: 19002
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 19006, host: 19006

    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "install.sh"

    config.vm.provision "set_lan_ip", "type": "shell" do |installs|
    installs.inline = "
      echo 'export REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=#{REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME}' >> /home/vagrant/.zshrc
    "
  end
end
```

When I run `npm start` I see information that expo start. I can see url and qr image:

```
Starting project at /home/vagrant/workspace/app
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Starting Metro Bundler
```

When I run localhost:19002 and 192.168.33.40:19002, I see: `This site can’t be reached`. But when I launch `expo start:web` and open: 192.168.33.40:19006 works fine... When I run `curl localhost:19002` on guest, I can see html, but the same cmd on host gets: Recv failure. (192.168.33.40 the same error).

I checked ports:

```
node      1116         vagrant   21u  IPv4  21603      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:19002 (LISTEN)
node      1116         vagrant   22u  IPv6  21661      0t0  TCP *:19000 (LISTEN)
node      1160         vagrant   20u  IPv6  21720      0t0  TCP *:19001 (LISTEN)
```

and where web is active:

```
node      1220         vagrant   22u  IPv4  22679      0t0  TCP *:19006 (LISTEN)
```

I think that it may be a problem with port. 19002 is mapped on localhost(127.0.0.1), but should allowed on all interfaces. Can I set it in expo?

Where is my mistake?

resources: https://github.com/jean553/react-native-dev, [Expo and Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625451/expo-and-vagrant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
export EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=192.168.33.40
```

I used a other parameter but this one is correct...